# How to create buttons with editable text that are re sizable (to accommodate longer/shorter text) on all browsers

Tags: css

I often find that I need to change the text on buttons.

I'd like to create some CSS based editable buttons with mouse over effects.
And the whole button should be clickable (not just the text).

I have heard that older browsers don't "stretch" images very well so maybe I'll need several variations of the CSS Class, each with a different image background.

Comment: This question is much better fit for stackoverflow. Technique for making a button with html and css has nothing to do with graphic design.

Comment: +1 for moving this to stackoverflow. The others are right about being able to do this with CSS3. No need for images. There are plenty of examples all over the net these days. Google for “CSS3 buttons.” :-)

Comment: The craft of making what you design is absolutely related to graphic design. That said, I agree that this question would be better served on SO.

Comment: Boo. Using HTML and CSS is as much Design as anything else. How is it not? Since it's done with code instead of a layered PSD?

Comment: I was talking about the technique. Maybe the "nothing to do with" line was a little too strict. The way it is related, is that it is the method to stitch up the design, and then we get back to the coding...

Comment: Expanding on what DA01 said, in principle, the technicalities of implementing a design make sense here. But in practice, these questions get better answered on SO (stackoverflow.com): CSS expert front-end developers have SO accounts and not GD accounts (they make the designs they're given); web designer-developers who know CSS here have SO accounts in addition to their GD accounts. It doesn't make sense for us to try to compete with or re-create the masses of great CSS content and expertise that already exists on stackoverflow.com - better to use each site for what each site is best at

Comment: Flagged for reopening since the FAQ clearly states this is on-topic. You're not competing with SO. This is a separate website from SO so even if more people will see it doesn't mean it doesn't belong here. I'm sure SEO and rich content for this site is just as valuable to SE as it is on SO.

Comment: @RKS I saw your flag but am not overriding the community's votes to close (in addition to the close votes, it was also flagged for close by others).  If it gets enough re-open votes, it will be reopened without mod intervention.

Comment: Isn't that what the FAQ is for and mods are for? To make sure things are running correctly? What good is a mod if they aren't even going to correct people when they're clearly wrong. Change the FAQ for what is allowed and then you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several techniques given modern browser support and CSS3.

The original technique was called Sliding Doors. It used two images inorder to allow the width of a button to stretch. An article covering how to set things up can be viewed [Here at alistapart.com](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/)

Given the advances in CSS, it is now possible to simply create the entire button without any images whatsoever. An article describing the CSS can be read [here at webdesignerwall.com](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-gradient-buttons) and there are even online [CSS button creators](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/).

This question is better suited for [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: +1 for stackoverflow. This can be completed using CSS3. See here. http://hellohappy.org/css3-buttons/

Comment: Ok removed downvote, you actually did add an answer to his question. I read your beginning and end and completely missed the middle section. However, he does mention older browsers so CSS3 is not going to be of use to him unless he decides not to support older browsers anymore.

Comment: Wow, what attitude. Who said I was deciding anything for anyone. I merely posted my answer. Which is what the site is designed for.

Comment: Jeez get a life. Before you even came here and commented I admitted mistake and edited my comment. Regardless, I know who's the guy to avoid and can't take any kind of criticism and starts rage-downvoting. Good to know.

Comment: To comment and downvote other answers for mentioing CSS3, then add an answer with the **very issue** you gave for downvoting.....

Answer (score 2):

-1 for moving it to SO. This is design related. Tell how it is not.

As for the answer: If you're set on doing this with images rather than CSS you will need 3 images. A left, a right, and a center. I assume you're going for the rounded button style so the right and left images are the rounded edges. The middle image is just the height to match the other two and the same background.

Note: if going for a gradient it won't work if you do it right to left but will work just fine if you do it top to bottom.

Now:

```
<span class="left"><a class="button" href="#">This is my expandable button</a></span>
```

or

```
<span class="left"><button class="button">This is my expandable button</button></span>
```

Css:

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; /*needs all vendor prefixes*/ }
.left { background: url(left.jpg) no-repeat; display: block; width: somthingpx; height: somethingpx; }
.button { background: url(middle.jpg) repeat-x; }
```

Comment: You don't need 3 images for sliding doors, you only need 2. And I posted a link to alistapart.com's sliding doors tutorial, which is much better than this answer. The * for CSS is very poor practice causing every DOM element to be interpreted by the CSS. In addition, you use the border-box declaration, which is a CSS3 declaration....yet you pan CSS3 in your answer as well.

Comment: This technique is not sliding doors. It's better and easier. The * is copied from the fiddle, which the end of my post was cut off for some reason. And besides, I did not pan CSS3 in my answer, I made note to you in YOUR answer that he might not be able to rely on CSS3.